# Функция мягкого знака после шипящих в конце глаголов

Tags: орфография, история, старая-орфография

Реформа-1918 отменила Ъ в конце существительных, как ненужный элемент русской орфографии.

Между тем, мягкий знак Ь сохраняется в написании после шипящих в конце глаголов :

пишешЬ, рисуешЬ, мажешЬся (2-е лицо,ед.ч.)

лечЬ, течЬ, сечЬ, беречЬся (инфинитив)

режЬ, прячЬся, плачЬ (повел.накл.)

Какую роль выполняет в данном случае мягкий знак? Мягкости он не обозначает, разделительным не является, на грамматический признак указывает только в слове 'плачЬ' ( глагол в пов.н., а не сущ. 'плач').

Итак, зачем нам нужен мягкий знак в указанных случаях, что говорит об этом передовая филологическая мысль?

Comment: Вас не удивляет, что ключ, нож, хвощ и ерш пишутся без мягкого знака, а ночь, рожь, вещь и брошь с ним?

Comment: Вопрос о глаголах, см. выше.

Comment: Действительно интересный вопрос, но думаю, что, кроме традиции, этот мягкий знак не оправдаешь, хотя мне нравится мнение, что он указывает на то, что слово глагол, но тогда возникают вопросы по поводу слов третьего склонения: ночь, ложь и т.д.

Comment: Вопрос о том, что вас удивляет. См. ниже.

Comment: Да, это традиция, в орфографии очень много построено на традиции. 
Тем удивительнее, что вопрос задан именно о глаголах, где эта традиция вполне себе оправдана смыслоразличительной функцией.

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы в русскую грамматику было введено следующее переходное правило: "Допускается писать знак "ь" в глаголах после шипящих букв во втором лице единственного числа. Однако, предпочтительнее не писать знак "ь" после шипящих букв во втором лице единственного числа." Примеры: 1. Допускается писать "[Ты] пишешь.", но предпочтительнее писать "[Ты] пишеш.". 2. Допускается писать "[Ты] рисуешь.", но предпочтительнее писать "[Ты] рисуеш.". 3. Допускается писать "[Ты] мажешься.", но предпочтительнее писать "[Ты] мажешся."

Comment: Ни в коем случае! Никаких "допускается"! Тут такое начнётся...
Мы "спотыкаемся", читая посты на интернетовских форумах. Не сразу грамотный человек расшифровывает "деффчёнки" и подобное. Я скорее соглашусь с Людмилой:Пусть школьники помнят, что во 2 лице РУССКИХ глаголов ВСЕГДА был и будет Ь.

Comment: "... К тому же отсутствие Ь на конце глаголов 2 лица одна из самых распространенных ошибок." (Элен)

Может быть, ошибаются не дети, а те грамматики, которые требуют сохранения знака "ь" на конце глаголов 2-го лица единственного числа после введения в употребление знака " " (пробел)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Вообще-то тоже для указания на принадлежность к части речи - глаголу. Он стоит на месте сверхкраткого [и]:  знаешь произносилось примерно как знаеши, . Затем редуцированный гласный [ь] во всех славянских языках исчез, а мягкий [ш] в русском языке отвердел.Но по традиции, чтобы напомнить, что он был, в глаголах остался Ь. То же самое в пекти-печи - печь и т.д.во всех глагольных формах.

Comment: В инфинитиве Ь хоть как-то оправдан, для соблюдения единообразия. В других формах Ь знак присутствует далеко не всегда. 
Писать, пишу, пишешЬ, пишет, пишем, пишете, пишут, пиши, пишите. Где, друзья, логика? Давайте уж тогда : он пишеть, они пишуть, мы пишемь, в знак того, что это глаголы! Почему только после шипящих? Самые безответные буквы, видимо; не могут за себя постоять.

Любиш кататься, люби и саночки возить.

Comment: В 3-м л. мн. ч. в древнерусских тоже был Ь:несоуть, идоуть, могоуть  В 1-м л. ед. ч.- есмь, дамь, емь, вемь, имамь).Потом изменения в фонетике,ь стал твёрдым (ъ)и исчез после реформы как ненужный, а во 2 лице после шипящих не было ъ,( шипящие всегда были мягкими)остался как показатель 2 лица.

Comment: А я согласна, что у глаголов 2-ого лица этот рудимент излишен. Это просто дань традиции. Но Ъ отменили безболезненно! К тому же отсутствие Ь на конце глаголов 2 лица одна из самых распространённых ошибок.

Comment: Не думаю, что это разумно.Если убрать все следы редуцированных, о них никто и не вспомнит.Меняется весь графический облик глагола 2 лица. Мы и так историю своей письменности не знаем. Пусть школьники помнят, что во 2 лице РУССКИХ глаголов ВСЕГДА был и будет Ь.Там вон другая тенденция - "новые славяне"пытаются на полном серьёзе вернуть еры, ерики, яти.Вот чего бойся.Вместо упрощения - усложнение. Думаю, этого не случится, люди в РАН разумные. А мы рассуждаем о ненужности Ь в
 -ешь/-ишь...

Answer (score 2):

Откуда взялись или почему остались?Ь-ерь- свидетельство того, что здесь был редуцированный гласный.ЛОЖЬ-др-р.*лъжа( лгать-лыгать, Залыгин - остаток)-Ъ прояснилось в О:диал. ложь стало нормой. Шипящие отвердели, Ъ и Ь предлагали убрать.Не дали из-за  морфологической аналогии. Слова жен.рода типа рожь, ночь дают одинаковую парадигму склонения со словами типа дверь ( дверь - дверью, рожь - рожью, ночь - ночью), в то время как слова мужского рода типа врач, шалаш имеют такую же парадигму, как и слова типа стол (стол - столом, врач - врачом, шалаш - шалашом).Ь указывает на ж.род в отличие от врач.

Comment: Людмила, с существительными все понятно, вопрос был задан мной по поводу глаголов. Мягкий знак в конце глаголов после шипящих))) Какая в глаголах парадигма нарушится, если мы будем писать : хочеш, можеш, придеш?

Comment: Ь ( редуцированное И )во 2 лице - показатель  2 лица -несеши, ведеши/несёшь, ведёшь.Возможно, чтобы различить знающ / знаешь. Т.е. по традиции остался.В формах инфинитива и повелительного наклонения - тоже по традиции, и добавилась  роль  графического уравнителя морфологических категорий повелительного наклонения: режь (как брось), а также инфинитива: беречь(как брать).Как и в сущ. 3 скл.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос, имхо, выеденного яйца не стоит.
Его надо ставить - не "откуда оно пошло" (это достаточно хорошо известно), а о том, почему сохранилось. Хотя попытки упразднить этот знак предпринимались неоднократно с двадцатых ещё годов. Но воз и ныне там - и слава богу.

Понятно, что ставить вопрос об упразднении Ь во всех трех случаях просто глупо, надо как минимум инфинитив из списка исключить по понятным причинам.

В отношении же двух других случаев, то у повелительного наклонения мягкий знак соответствует редуцированному И, который присутствует во всех формах без шипящего. Тому свидетельства: иди, паси, лай, запрягай, и даже нелитературное "едь".

Остается только 2-е лицо ед. ч. Вот оно-то вполне может остаться без мягкого знака, что и предлагалось в своё время еще комиссией Луначарского.

Comment: shampar, можно вас попросить в дальнейшем не привносить пять своих ошибок, исправляя три моих опечатки?

Comment: мягкий знак отсутствует в повелительном наклонении глагола **лечь** - **ляг**, или для сохранения единообразия правильной формой должно быть **ляжь**?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема окончаний неразрешима до тех пор , пока не будет установлен общий для русского языка принцип написания - фонетический, морфологический или пальцевысасываемый.
В украинском языке , несмотря на то, что он тоже вырос из старославянского, проблем в написании слов данной категории не существует - там мягкий звук просто не ставится, поскольку имеющийся перед ним шипящий звук не смягчается в произношени.
Думаю, должен восторжествовать разум и в качестве единственного принципа в русском языке всё - таки восторжествует  фонетический принцип написания слов.

Comment: Если фонетический принцип восторжествует, мы перестанем понимать друг друга. Он может восторжествовать не раньше, чем исчезнут диалекты.

Comment: Вы не правы. 
Вы можете понимать друг друга с помощью письма.

Comment: Как же! Один будет писать ишо, другой ящё, третий ищо...
И я могу ещё предложить несколько вариантов написания этого простого слова)))

Comment: Иван, переведите пожалуйста на русский язык слова, которые я в устной речи слышу почти каждый день: *рарышыте, пасипа, пажаста*. Если Вам вне контекста понятны эти общеупотребительные слова, то тогда вполне можно переходить на фонетический принцип письма, если же затруднения всё же возникли, то лучше будет остаться на морфемно-историческом.

Comment: Разрешите, спасибо, пожалуйста. )))Дети часто пишут, как слышат. Но колбасу с солями (салями) и кагибута (как будто) - даже я не угадала вне контекста. В последнем диктанте в новом классе: уйти в старушку (вместо в сторожку). Вот Вам и фонетический принцип в действии.